# Can a sharepoint online application with multiple lists run queries to produce reports like a Database

Tags: sharepoint-online, office

is this possible? Is there a limit to the number of datasets I can access? If I extract via excel, will it be a live version of the data or a snapshot.

Comment: what kind of reports are you looking to get?

Comment: The data you pull using Data Sources in Excel is live and can be refreshed manually.

Answer (score 0):

with MS-Excel you can only open one SharePoint List (Read-only)

With MS-Access you can link to all SharePoint Lists (to Access they are Tables)

And MS-Access can write back to SharePoint

MS-Access is powerful for reporting (use all the Access Wizards)